# Data not applying separator to csv file while concatenating in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, separator, merging-data

I have a set of csv files that I am trying to concat. I am having issues that the concatenated file does not apply the comma separators to the content. Given below is the code:

```
##Location where the csv files are located
updatedfiles = glob.glob(LOCAL_PATH2 + "/*.csv")

#Applying comma separator to the concatenated output
df_v1 = [pd.read_csv(fp, sep=',', delim_whitespace=True).assign(FileName=os.path.basename(fp)) for fp in updatedfiles]
```

Could anyone guide me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe need to remove `delim_whitespace=True`, because 2 separators `,` and whitespace. If need both `sep='\s+|,'` should working or parameter `skipinitialspace=True` it need remove trailing whitespaces.

[`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **delim_whitespace** : boolean, default False
>
> Specifies whether or not whitespace (e.g. ' ' or '\t') will be used as the sep. Equivalent to setting sep='\s+'. If this option is set to True, nothing should be passed in for the delimiter parameter.